# How to use sigma grid editor type checkbox?

Tags: jquery, sigma-grid-control

is there any ways to set the value of checkbox on sigma grid??

i don't see any configuration that could change it

maybe anyone ever try it?

i need the checkbox value to change, so that the rows checked will be send to be updated.

that is the only way to get all record sent

Answer (score 0):

It appears (I am trying to figure out the checkbox too) that there is NO VALUE assigned to the checkboxes at all. They are ignored when passed.

But I am working on extending the following snippet which works at the JS level:

```
for ( var row_id in mygrid.checkedRows) 
          { //check which rows have been Ticked
          console.log('selected row: '+row_id+' '+mygrid.checkedRows[row_id]);
          console.log('Row data: ' +mygrid.getCellValue('uid',row_id));
          }
```

Where uid is the name of the column which denotes the Unique Identifier of that row. (the checkedRows array is 0-based)

Comment: This fails if the user has changed the page size.